# Zend framework - addPrefixPath and namespaces

Tags: zend-framework

I tried to use $element->addPrefixPath() to load my custom validator but it would not find the class until I added a namespace autoload to the ini file.

I thought the whole point of addPrefixPath was to only load the validator class for the form and not the whole application. Is this correct?

Comment: Did you add an absolute or a relative path?

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon how you invoke the validator and attach it to the element:

1. Using an instance
2. Using "abbreviated" format (my own terminology)

As an instance:

```
$validator = new My_Validate_SomeValidator(array(
    'option1' => 'value1',
    'option2' => 'value2',
));
$element->addValidator($validator, true);
```

In this case, you are instantiating the validator yourself. So, adding `My_` as an autoloader namespace is required.

Alternatively, using the "abbreviated" format:

```
$element->addValidator(array('SomeValidator', array(
    'option1' => 'value1',
    'option2' => 'value2',
), true);
```

or

```
$element->setValidators(array(
    array('EmailAddress', true),
    array('SomeValidator', true, array(
        'option1' => 'value1',
        'option2' => 'value2',
    ),
));
```

In this case, you are giving the element only an abbreviated name - `'SomeValidator'` - for the validator, implicitly expecting the *element* to handle the instantiation. So it makes sense that the element needs to be given some namespace/path information so it can do the job.